# disable click on events on fullcalendar getting google feed

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar getting the feed from public google calendar, and works perfectly but I need that the events are not clickable, and right now it open the event info on google.

I try to use "evenclick" but no success:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
             if (event.url) {
            window.open(event.url);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I search on answered questions but only find a couple of ones that seem outdated

thx in advance.

Comment: why opening a window? just return false. might work

Comment: how can I do it with google calendar feed?